# Java creating a game via youtube instructions, cannot figure out why the code won't run

Tags: java

I am learning the basics

I am learning Java

I am using the program Eclipse.

Let's start with the simplest issue. So far I have 9 issues across my code, but one in particular is the one I have in the GameStateManager class.

Line 26, or gameState.get(currentState).init();

It says "Cannot invoke get(int) on the primitive type (int)."
 Can somebody explain that error to me?

```
package GameState;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameStateManager {

    private ArrayList<GameState> gameStates;
    private int currentState;
    private int gameState;

    public static final int MENUSTATE = 0;
    public static final int LEVEL1STATE = 1;

    public GameStateManager() {

        gameStates = new ArrayList<GameState>();

        currentState = MENUSTATE;
        gameStates.add(new MenuState(this));


    }
public void setState(int state)
        { 
            currentState = state; 
            gameState.get(currentState).init(); <[ERROR]
        }

    public void update() { 
        gameStates.get(currentState).update();
     }
    public void draw(java.awt.Graphics2D g) {
        }   
    public void keyPressed(int k){
        gameStates.get(currentState).keyPressed(k); }
    public void keyReleased(int k){
        gameStates.get(currentState).keyReleased(k); }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just misspelled it. Change `gameState` to `gameStates`:

```
gameStates.get(currentState).init();
```

Comment: I'm so disappointed in myself, one of my first code errors was the same as this and locating this miss spelling X.x. Thank you ,Ka4eli!

Answer (score 0):

`gameState` is indeed a primitive `int`. I'm assuming you meant to use `gameStates` (note the plural form), which is indeed an `ArrayList<GameState>`, which has a `get(int)` method.